# Books versus YouTube videos

Tags: community

I was wondering, and hope this question is not too broad, but these days, what are the advantages of writing a book versus making a series of YouTube videos? Do people read any more, or do they just watch videos online instead of cinema movies, television, and yes, books.

So, what kind of books habe YouTube videos made obsolete and how do I chose which is best for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about "How To..." books versus "DIY..." videos, then there is probably some grounds to argue that YouTube is biting into book sales.  But for any process which takes more than 5 minutes to master, or for anything that needs to happen more a few feet from your computer's screen, I think that even that genre still has a purpose.

As for the rest of the realms of non-fiction, nothing beats a book.  The longest television documentary on any subject pales before the depth and completeness of a competently written textbook.  Using a video as a reference document requires scrolling to the right spot in the timeline and the home pages of few YouTube videos come with time-stamp indices.

As for fiction, radio, cinema, and television have been attacking the dominance of the written word for decades.  YouTube brings nothing new to that battle.

If you have valuable thoughts and ideas... write them down!

Comment: I can read a helluva lot faster than I can watch. There are some tasks for which a demo video makes sense, like a How To, but for 95% of subjects, I would MUCH rather read, *anything*, than sit through another damn video.